# How to find tangent planes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-approximation

Finding the tangent plane equation is simple for equations with a simple $z$. For example, if $z$ is a function $f(x,y)$ such as $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. It's simply:

$z-z_0=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$

Which in that case would be:

$z-z_0=(2x)(x-x_0)+(3y^2)(y-y_0)$

But what if we're dealing with a more complicated $f(x,y,z)$ where values are not necessarily unique along the $z$ axis?

Wouldn't we have to add a $f_z$ term?

Comment: Are you talking about level sets of $f(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by "a more complicated $f(x,y,z)$"? Something like $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$?

Answer (score 2):

The gradient vector
$$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} ,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)$$
is normal to the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$. If $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on your surface then the tangent plane is the plane passing through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and perpendicular to $(\nabla f)(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

If you have some set given by several equations, say $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$, then the tangent space to this set is given by [kernel vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

*I have assumed that everything here is smooth and intersections are transverse.

Answer (score 0):

Extend implicit function like e.g., $ f(x,y,z) =x^2+y^3-1/z $ to include $z$

$f_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+f_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)=0.$

Comment: The standard equation I listed in two dimensions can also b,

$f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)-(z-z_0)=0$


Why isn't there a negative in the equation you listed?

Comment: Try to obtain your special case total differential of 3 dimns from the general implicit form I gave.